# Can Core Animations supports a 20 frames per second enlargement from 32 x 32 px to 120 x 170 px?

Tags: iphone, opengl, iphone-sdk-3.0, core-animation, cocos2d-iphone

my background.jpg has 52 32x32 mini poker cards.png and when user touch on 1 card, it will enlarge to 120x 170 px.

At any point in time, there is only 1 card being chosen (i.e, being animated) with at most 19 entire cards overlapped (120x170 / 32x32).

Should i use Core Animation or do i have to learn OpenGL or use a library such as cocos2d?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure Core Animation can handle that. If your cards are `UIImageViews` you can probably just use something like:

```
UIImageView * card; // Assume this is a valid UIImageView
[UIView beginAnimations@"CardZoom" context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration 0.8]; // However long you want
card.frame = CGRectMake(newX, newY, 120, 170); // set to final position and size
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Comment: Thank you very much!!! my cards are UIImageViews but each card has 20 png images to animate within 1 second... will it slow down? i have recently enrolled for the dev program, hence i'm unable to test the animations on my phone.

Answer (score 0):

If performance is an issue, OpenGL is the way to go.  But your application of 52 sprites shouldn't tax most devices.